# Deleting new duplicates but not the old ones

Tags: vba, excel

so I have a column with a lot of data (around 8,000 cells), and I want to add new cells. Some of these cells are duplicates, and I'd like to remove them. However, there are already some duplicates in these 8,000 original cells that can't remove. So `RemoveDuplicates` won't work.
What I'm trying to do is to get a fast way of getting it, so not with a `For` that goes trough every cell, which would be my second choice.

This is what I've been trying to do (It's a big code, but this is the part that counts):

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range("D5", .Range("D5").End(xlDown)
      .ClearFormats 'this part I copied from macro recording basically
      .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
      .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
      .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
        End With
      .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
      .Range("D5", .Range("D5").End(xlDown)).Calculate
      'Calculation is manual, so I'm putting this in case it's not doing the formatting now
      End With
    For Each Cell In .Range("D" & First_Row_of_new_data, .Range("D5").End(xlDown))
    'I'm trying to delete all cells which have changed colors, meaning they're duplicates
        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 13551615 Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
```

The problem here is that the last part isn't doing anything. All variables have been properly defined earlier.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A cell that is colored due to conditional formatting does not show the color as the value of the `Interior.ColorIndex` property

Comment: Okay, thanks for that! Do you have any clue of how can i get the cells?

Comment: Normally, I'd recommend evaluating the format condition in your loop. For example, if the conditional format fills a cell when the value is greater than 10, you can instead add a conditional to your loop. In your case, the format condition seems a bit more complicated. Just to clarify your post, the original data set (the 8,000 cells) does this have repeated/duplicate values? Or are they all unique?

Comment: The original data set has duplicate values already, and for reasons that are unclear to me, I can't delete those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got beat to the post, but I'll add mine since I coded it. Obviously, make the necessary changes. I'd also consider deleting the row directly, versus coloring it, then deleting it after the fact.

```
Sub DeleteNewDuplicates()
    Dim rngOriginal As Range
    Dim rngNewData As Range
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rIterator As Range
    Dim nLastRowNewData As Long
    Dim t As Single

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    t = Timer

    'Assume the original data is range A1:A25, and it may contain duplications
    Set rngOriginal = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8000")

    'New Data is added from A26 to A100
    Set rngNewData = Sheet1.Range("A8001:A120075")

    'Create a dictionary to hold the unique values in the original range
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Add unique values to the dictionary
    For Each rIterator In rngOriginal
        'If not already in the dictionary, add it, otherwise ignore
        If Not oDict.exists(rIterator.Value) Then
            oDict.Add rIterator.Value, ""
        End If
    Next rIterator

    'Need to loop throw the new range in reverse so as to not skip rows
    nLastRowNewData = rngNewData.Range("A1").Offset(rngNewData.Rows.Count).Row - 1

    For i = nLastRowNewData To rngNewData.Range("A1").Row Step -1
        'If it is in the dictionary, then it is a duplicate and we can delete
        If oDict.exists(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
            Sheet1.Rows(i).Delete
        Else
            'Otherwise add it to the dictionary so it doesn't get repeated
            oDict.Add Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, ""
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Process took approximately ... " & Timer - t & " seconds."

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you very much!
I love this website

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do what you need to do is to use Dictionary structure. E.g., you simply add every value you meet in a range to a dictionary and if it exists, you consider marking it for deletion. In the case below, you should delete the cells with `<` next to them:

[image]
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim myDict  As Object

    Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myRange = Range("A1:A11")

    For Each myCell In myRange
        Debug.Print myCell
        If myDict.exists(CStr(myCell)) Then
            myCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            myDict.Add CStr(myCell), 1
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Thus, after executing the first code, you would get the picture to the right. In order to remove the cells in red, you should loop from 11 to 1:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cnt     As Long

    Set myRange = Range("A1:A11")

    For cnt = myRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(cnt, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            Cells(cnt, 1).Delete
        End If
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

In order to upgrade further the code, consider making it work if the first row is not number 1 and `myRange` is not hardcoded.